# Why does my Raspberry Pi automatically mount SD cards and how do I stop it?

Tags: sd-card, mount

I am running Raspbian Jessie with Pixel desktop from a USB flash drive on my Rpi3 so I can use the SD slot for other purposes. However, whenever I plug in an SD card while the system is running, I will get a message saying an SD card has been plugged in. It automatically mounts it to `/media/pi/<vendorId/productId`. I do not want this. I haven't installed anything since the first boot except for `qtcreator`.

I do not want the system to mount the SD card for me by creating its own mountpoint without asking me first. How can I stop this behavior?

*(Normally I'd be happy with it automatically mounting storage so I can use it easily. But this is a development machine and a strict requirement is that it does not mount SD cards automatically.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to removing the whole `udisks2` package (as suggested in the answer first given), you may instead want to overwrite the default rule for `mmcblk[0-9]` from the distributed configuration file 
`/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules`.  For this purpose create a file for example named `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2-nosdcard.rules` and put a copy of the line from the default configuration file augmented with the option 
`ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"` into it.
After editing it might be required to restart the `udisksd` daemon process using for example the command:

```
sudo service udisks2 restart
```

Comment: You should never edit the configuration file directly in the `/lib/udev/rules/` directory. Any change, like an update, to `udev`/`udisks2` will overwrite this. Not only is this not recommended in the documentation, it even say so directly at the top of the rules file.

Comment: You are right: For some reason I overlooked that the path was starting with `/lib` instead of `/etc`.

Comment: I've changed my answer according to your hint.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing [`udisks` or `udisks2`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286588/106927) packages. Please check the list before removing, since AFAIK those packages are pulled as dependencies of your desktop environment, and you don't want to remove that.

Comment: I found out that it is indeed `udisks2`. Using `d-feet` I explored the `udisks2` D-bus interfaces and for my block device (SD card) found that the AutoHint was true. Looking in the udisks2 documentation I found this decided if the device was mounted automatically. To fix this, I have to place a specific rule for this in the `udisks2` rules file under `/etc/udev/rules`. This answer is not really what I'm looking for as this removes `udisks2` entirely, possibly bringing down other (automount) features as well.